# How to calculate the mean,max,min,range,mode and median of the data in csv file and return value in 2d array

Tags: python-3.x

How to calculate mean,median,min max and mode of the data in csv file and return the values in 2d array? (python)

```
Data =   Employee_name,Date,Salary,Age
         Ramesh,04/04/19,20000,25
         Mahesh,04/04/19,10000,30
         John,04/04/19,15000,15
         Watson,05/04/19,19000,20
```

This is my code:
data = pd.read_csv('Data_file.csv')

for line in data:

```
   print line

   try:         

       mean= (round(getattr(data,line).mean(),2))

   except:

       mean= ("__")

   try:         

       min= (round(getattr(data,line).min(),2))

   except:

       min= ("__")
   try:         

       max= (round(getattr(data,line).max(),2))

   except:

       max= ("__")
   try:         

       range=(round(getattr(data,line).max()-(getattr(data,line).min()),2))

   except:

       range= ("__")
   try:         

       std= (round(getattr(data,line).std(),2))

   except:

       std= ("__")
   try:         

       mode=round(getattr(data,line).mode()[0],2)

   except:

       mode= ("__")

   try:         

       kurt=round(getattr(data,line).kurtosis(),2)

   except:

       kurt= ("__")
   try:         

       skew= (round(getattr(data,line).skew(),2))

   except:

       skew= ("__")

   try:         

       med= (round(getattr(data,line).median(),2))

   except:

       med= ("__")

   try:         

       var= (round(getattr(data,line).var(),2))

   except:

       var= ("__")


   Mean=[ ]

   Min= [ ]

   Max= [ ]

   Range= [ ]

   Standard_deviation=[ ]

   Mode=[ ]

   Kurtosis=[ ]

   Skewness=[ ]

   Median=[ ]

   Sample_Variance=[ ]

   Mean.append(mean)

   Min.append(min)

   Max.append(max)

   Range.append(range)

   Standard_deviation.append(std)

   Mode.append(mode)

   Kurtosis.append(kurt)

   Skewness.append(skew)

   Median.append(med)

   Sample_Variance.append(var)

   print(Mean,Min,Max,Range,Standard_deviation,Mode,Kurtosis,Skewness,Median,Sample_Variance)
```

Here by using try and except i handled exception for employeee_name and date.
For further i have no idea. i am new in python

Comment: Which fields you want to use: Salary and Age? What did you try so far?

Comment: For salary and age but for Employee_name and Date ,we need to handle exception

Comment: Share your current code please

Comment: Have a look at pandas.